# What is wrong with this elastic search groovy script?

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I am trying to dynamically add a field using groovy script where if the field exists then just add a new element to the array,if not then create the field with the first value.

```
if(!ctx._source.containsKey(\"Activities\")) { ctx._source.Activities = [activity] }else{ctx._source.Activities += activity}
```

I am passing the activity param properly but this operation is returning a error:

> "remote_transport_exception:
>   [Stonecutter][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/write/update[s]]"

Do you guys have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The map object of your Doc does not support the "+=" operator, u can checkout the right way to update the Doc in the official guide.